# Generating subsets with 1 common element

Tags: combinatorics

I have a number $n$ and a set $S$ of $n(n-1)/2$ elements :  $ \{1, 2, \ldots, n(n-1)/2\}$

I'm looking for an algorithm to generate $n$ **distinct** subsets of $S$, each having $n-1$ elements, with the following property:
For any combination of $n-1$ subsets, their union will be the set $S = \{1, 2, \ldots, n(n-1)/2\}$.

I think (I'm not sure) that this is equivalent to there being at most one common element between any two subsets.

For example if $n = 4$, I need to generate 4 subsets of 3 elements where S is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

A(The?) solution would be

$1 2 3,
1 4 5,
2 4 6,
3 5 6$

Comment: $123, 124, 356, 456$ would work, as would $123, 123, 456, 456$. As long as each element of $S$ occurs in more than one subset, the union of $n-1$ subsets will be $S$

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention that the subsets must be distinct.

Comment: That only rules out my second example. My first example has four distinct subsets, with two pairs of subsets having two common elements. This is contrary to your equivalence hypothesis.

Comment: $S$ is a set of $n(n-1)/2$ elements, but does $S$ **have** to be the set $\{1,2,\dots,n(n-1)/2\}$? Would it be OK if I could construct a family of $n$ subsets satisfying your conditions for some **other** set $S$ with $n(n-1)/2$ elements?

Comment: Isn't it equivalent since by definition a set cannot have duplicates ? If S is not ${1,2,…,n(n−1)/2}$, you can map any set with $n(n-1)/2$ to S.

Comment: If there is at most one common element between any two subsets, then the union of $n-1$ subsets will be the set $S$. But, as I demonstrated in my first comment, there exist solutions where subsets can have more than one common element.

Comment: @Logophobic yes i didnt read ur remark at first, but u were right

Comment: Great! Let $V=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ be some set of $n$ (distinct) elements. Now let $S$ be the set of all $2$-element subsets of $V.$ For example, if $n=4,$ then $V=\{v_1v_2,v_1v_3,v_1v_4,v_2v_3,v_2v_4,v_3v_4\}.$ (To save typing I write $v_1v_2$ instead of $\{v_1,v_2\},$ etc.) Now let $A_i$ be the set of all $2-$ element subsets containing $v_i$; in the example with $n=4$ we have $A_1=\{v_1v_2,v_1v_3,v_1v_4\},$ etc. Then $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ are $n$ distinct sets, each with $n-1$ elements . . .

Comment: Your solution seems to work! Thanks !